# preprocessing.StandardScaler(). deals with string features?

Tags: pca

I am trying to train a model for classification.

My dataset has 42 features, some are string values and the others are float value.

I want to use `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` on the dataset and then used PCA to reduce the dimensions. How should I deal with the string values?  Using `LabelEncoder`? is it also for dealing with the features but not the labels?